# IdP initiated SSO with Azure B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am using Azure B2C as an IAM solution for one of our product. I have created custom policies to establish the integrations between the IDP and B2C and SP initiated SSO are working fine. However, during IdP initiated SSO it keeps on complaining “AADB2C90031: Policy "B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkBase" does not specify a default user journey. Ensure that the policy or it's parents specify a default user journey as part of a relying party section.”

However, within the custom policy the user journey is defined and have followed several suggestions like adding “IdpInitiatedProfileEnabled = true” within Technical profile etc. But still the same error. Any suggestion please what might be going wrong.

Here is an example of the custom policy that I am using:

```
    <TrustFrameworkPolicy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06" PolicySchemaVersion="0.3.0.0" TenantId="mycorphreudevadb2c.onmicrosoft.com" PolicyId="B2C_1A_signup_signin_mycorpHRBE" DeploymentMode="Development" UserJourneyRecorderEndpoint="urn:journeyrecorder:applicationinsights" PublicPolicyUri="http://mycorphreudevadb2c.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_signup_signin_mycorpHRBE" TenantObjectId="2e099f2a-d6d8-4d0c-9e35-6cbffc5abc75">
      <BasePolicy>
        <TenantId>mycorphreudevadb2c.onmicrosoft.com</TenantId>
        <PolicyId>B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions</PolicyId>
      </BasePolicy>
      <ClaimsProviders>
        <ClaimsProvider>
          <Domain>mycorpHRBE</Domain>
          <DisplayName>mycorpHRBE</DisplayName>
          <TechnicalProfiles>
            <TechnicalProfile Id="mycorpHRBE">
              <DisplayName>mycorpHRBE</DisplayName>
              <Description>Login with your mycorpHRBE account</Description>
              <Protocol Name="SAML2" />
              <Metadata>
                <!-- <Item Key="WantsEncryptedAssertions">false</Item> -->
                <!-- <Item Key="WantsSignedAssertions">false</Item> -->
                <Item Key="PartnerEntity">https://login.microsoftonline.com/582d014d-08bb-4a66-8d1b-bd9ea1d49c35/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml?appid=96915106-4c12-43ef-b23e-a2bf7c7f9ee0</Item>
                <!-- Added for IDP Initated SSO From the Extrnal IDP SIde -->
                <Item Key="IdpInitiatedProfileEnabled">true</Item>
              </Metadata>
              <CryptographicKeys>
                <Key Id="SamlAssertionSigning" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_DevB2CSigningCert" />
                <Key Id="SamlMessageSigning" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_DevB2CSigningCert" />
              </CryptographicKeys>

              <!-- Input Claims used fro IDP Initiated SSO -->

              <InputClaims>
                <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier" />
                <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname" />
                <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" PartnerClaimType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname" />
                <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="email" />
                <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name" />
                <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" />
                <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="AzureAD" />
              </InputClaims>

              <OutputClaims>
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" PartnerClaimType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="email" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="AzureAD" />
              </OutputClaims>
              <OutputClaimsTransformations>
                <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName" />
                <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName" />
                <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId" />
                <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId" />
              </OutputClaimsTransformations>
              <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
            </TechnicalProfile>
          </TechnicalProfiles>
        </ClaimsProvider>
      </ClaimsProviders>
      <UserJourneys>
        <UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignInmycorpHRBE">
          <OrchestrationSteps>
            <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
              <ClaimsProviderSelections>
                <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="mycorpHRBEQASExchange" />
                <!-- <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" /> -->
              </ClaimsProviderSelections>
              <ClaimsExchanges>
                <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
              </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>
            <!-- Check if the user has selected to sign in using one of the social providers -->
            <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
              <Preconditions>
                <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                  <Value>objectId</Value>
                  <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                </Precondition>
              </Preconditions>
              <ClaimsExchanges>
                <ClaimsExchange Id="mycorpHRBEQASExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="mycorpHRBE" />
                <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
              </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>
            <!-- For social IDP authentication, attempt to find the user account in the directory. -->
            <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
              <Preconditions>
                <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                  <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
                  <Value>localAccountAuthentication</Value>
                  <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                </Precondition>
              </Preconditions>
              <ClaimsExchanges>
                <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadUsimycorplternativeSecurityId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsimycorplternativeSecurityId-NoError" />
              </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>
            <!-- Show self-asserted page only if the directory does not have the user account already (i.e. we do not have an objectId). 
              This can only happen when authentication happened using a social IDP. If local account was created or authentication done
              using ESTS in step 2, then an user account must exist in the directory by this time. -->
            <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
              <Preconditions>
                <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                  <Value>objectId</Value>
                  <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                </Precondition>
              </Preconditions>
              <ClaimsExchanges>
                <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAsserted-Social" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-Social" />
              </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>
            <!-- This step reads any user attributes that we may not have received when authenticating using ESTS so they can be sent 
              in the token. -->
            <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
              <Preconditions>
                <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                  <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
                  <Value>socialIdpAuthentication</Value>
                  <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                </Precondition>
              </Preconditions>
              <ClaimsExchanges>
                <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
              </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>
            <!-- The previous step (SelfAsserted-Social) could have been skipped if there were no attributes to collect 
                 from the user. So, in that case, create the user in the directory if one does not already exist 
                 (verified using objectId which would be set from the last step if account was created in the directory. -->
            <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="ClaimsExchange">
              <Preconditions>
                <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                  <Value>objectId</Value>
                  <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                </Precondition>
              </Preconditions>
              <ClaimsExchanges>
                <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserWrite" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsimycorplternativeSecurityId" />
              </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>
            <OrchestrationStep Order="7" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
          </OrchestrationSteps>
          <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
        </UserJourney>
      </UserJourneys>
      <RelyingParty>
        <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignInmycorpHRBE" />
        <UserJourneyBehaviors>
          <JourneyInsights TelemetryEngine="ApplicationInsights" InstrumentationKey="a71178bb-2de4-4537-9183-fd17ed016bb5" DeveloperMode="true" ClientEnabled="true" ServerEnabled="true" TelemetryVersion="1.0.0" />
        </UserJourneyBehaviors>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
          <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{Policy:TenantObjectId}" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </RelyingParty>
    </TrustFrameworkPolicy>
```

Comment: Try to follow my guidance here https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/saml-sp/tree/master/policy/SAML-Idp-Initiated. idp initiated isnt fully supported yet, hence lack of docs.

Comment: The policy to execute is part of the SAML AuthN Req Destination: `<samlp:Response xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ID="_1302947108" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2020-06-02T14:32:46.2938218Z" Destination="https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/b2cprod.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_SAMLTEST/samlp/sso/assertionconsumer" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
`

Comment: Hi Jas, thank you so much for you reply. I have reviewed your blog, and added the parameter you have suggested, still same error. Here we are using B2C to accept an IdP initiated call, is there something that needs to be taken care at IdP configuration? For PoC I am using Azure AD as an IdP.

Comment: You can see here https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/idpinitiated-sign-on-with-azure-ad-73e252c9c370 that the user sign on url in AAD SAML App is the Destination in SAML req. My advise is to use our test app first so you can isolate your issue.